# How to add a column to query results in Google Dataflow

Tags: kotlin, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read a query from BigQuery and then with Apache Beam / Dataflow in Kotlin I want to add a column with the current date as a timestamp. I don't want to do it inside the query itself because I want to reuse this code for a big amount of queries and it looks like a better design.

This is the pipeline code I wrote:

```kotlin
val pipeline = Pipeline.create(options)
  .apply("Retrieve query", BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(query).usingStandardSql())
  .apply("Add date", ParDo.of(AddDate()))
  .apply("Store data", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().withSchema(tableSchema)
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    .to(TableReference().setProjectId(gcpProject).setDatasetId(datasetId).setTableId(tableId))
```

For some reason it does not advance from the `Add date` transformation.
This is the code which is most likely to have the bug / error:

```kotlin
class AddDate : DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() {

    @ProcessElement
    fun processElement(context: ProcessContext) {
        val tableRow = context.element() as TableRow
        tableRow.set("process_date", Instant.now())
        context.output(tableRow)
    }
}
```

I also tried with this code instead inside `processElement`, but still does not work.

```kotlin
context.outputWithTimestamp(context.element(), Instant.now())
```

The error is the following:

> Input values must not be mutated in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by using a new object and being careful with the type used for the date (for `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` types)

```kotlin
@ProcessElement
fun processElement(context: ProcessContext) {
    val tableRow = TableRow()
    tableRow.set("process_date", Instant.now().toString())
    val input = context.element() as TableRow
    input.keys.forEach { tableRow.set(it, input[it]) }
    context.output(tableRow)
}
```